# Add a column of Data to a CSV file to a specific column in the middle

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, streamwriter

I'm using C# and Visual Studio Express 2010. I have a column of a datatable that I want to insert into a CSV file that already has some data. I want to send the data to the fifth column specifically. What I did was create a datatable and the following line to add a column.

```
datatable.Columns.Add("Data Added");
```

Then I added data from a process through

```
DataRow dtr = datatable.NewRow();
dtr["Data Added"] = DataFromProcess;
datatable.Rows.Add(dtr);
```

I used a streamwriter to write code to a csv file

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\CSVFile.csv"))
 {
    MyOwnWriter.WriteDataTable(dt, writer, true);
 }
```

where MyOwnWriter is a writing process from another class made specifically to write data.
What this is doing is replacing all columns in CSV file and just writing over them. Is there any way to access only the fifth column and write to it ? I'm not very fluent in C# so please be patient in explaining. Thank you.
Also, I use Microsoft excel to view csv files.